# Solve $\lim_{x \to 0}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ Using $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 1$

Tags: calculus, limits

Solve $\lim_{x \to 0}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})$ Using $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 1$

I have solved it using the Squeeze Theorem and now I want to solve it using $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 1$.

Why can't I multiply the numerator and denominator by $\frac{1}{x}$ so I can have it in the form of $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\frac{1}{x}x\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}} = \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}$ so that I can apply $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 1$.

I understand that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ does not exist, so does that mean that I can't solve the above mentioned using $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin \theta}{\theta} = 1$?

Comment: The fact that $\lim_{\theta\to 0} \frac{\sin\theta}{\theta}=1$ is not relevant to the problem. Squeezing is the way to go.

Comment: I was just curious to see if I can apply that type of method after I already solved it using the Squeeze Theorem. So would you say that there's no way for me to solve it using $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}$?

Comment: I understand now, thanks, @AndréNicolas.

Comment: Yes, I would say there is no way. We need the behaviour of $\sin z$ for large $z$, and the behaviour of $\sin t$ for small $t$ is not relevant. Note for example that $\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{e^t-1}{t}=1$, but the behaviour of $x(e^{1/x}-1)$ is entirely different from the behaviour of $x\sin(1/x)$ for $x$ near $0$.

Comment: The limit is $0$ as $sin\frac1x$ is bounded.

Comment: Related (proof using squeeze theorem|: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1066434/calculate-lim-x-to-0-x-cdot-sin-frac1x

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you would need to have $\frac1x\rightarrow 0$, but that's not the case.

And it's even worse:

- as $x\rightarrow 0+$, you have $\frac1x\rightarrow +\infty$
- as $x\rightarrow 0-$, you have $\frac1x\rightarrow -\infty$

Comment: Yes, that much I understand hence including "I understand that $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}$ does not exist, so does that mean that I can't solve the above mentioned using $\lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{\sin(\theta)}{\theta}$?", or am I misunderstanding what you're saying?

Comment: What I mean is you don't have $\theta\rightarrow 0$, so that formula doesn't apply. If the problem were something like $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}x\sin\frac1x$$ you could used that formula. But it isn't. You seem to be overlooking that the formula requires the expression in the denominator, which is also the argument of the sine, must approach zero to apply.

Comment: Now I get it, indeed that is what I was overlooking. Thanks for the insight, @MPW, I appreciate it.

Comment: You're quite welcome. Glad to be of assistance. :)