# Calculate: $ \lim_{x \to 0 } = x \cdot \sin(\frac{1}{x}) $

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

Evaluate the limit:
$$ \lim_{x \to 0 } = x \cdot \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) $$

So far I did:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0 } = x\frac{\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)}{\frac{1}{x}\cdot x}
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to 0 } = 1 \cdot \frac{x}{x}
$$

$$
\lim_{x \to 0 } = 1
$$

Now of course I've looked around and I know I'm wrong, but I couldn't understand why. Can someone please show me how to evaluate this limit correctly? And tell me what I was doing was wrong.

Comment: **Hint**: use the squeeze theorem.

Comment: How did you go from the first line to the second? ($\lim_{x\rightarrow0}{\sin(1/x)\over 1/x}\ne 1$.)

Comment: I used: $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$

Comment: No, that's not right. Look closely...

Comment: Can you please tell me :D?

Comment: If the argument of the $\sin$, call it $w$, tends to $0$, then ${\sin w\over w}$ tends to $0$. That's not what you have; the argument in your expression tends to $\pm\infty$, loosely speaking. On the other hand, $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}{\sin(1/x)\over 1/x} =1$, since $1/x\rightarrow0$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$.

Comment: OK, let's say I got you.. so you say I can use $$\lim_{x \to c} \frac{sinc}{c} = 1$$ only if $c$ is getting closer to $0$? and because $\frac{1}{x}$ approaches $\infty$ when $ x \to 0$ that is not valid? Do you have an idea how to evaluate it using the trigonometric identities?

Comment: Almost right; your notation is off. If $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} g(x)=0$, then $\lim_{x\rightarrow c} {\sin g(x)\over g(x)}=0$. You can't appeal to this for $g(x)=1/x$ and $c=0$.

Comment: Just use the squeeze theorem: $$0\le|x\sin(1/x)|\le |x|\ \buildrel{x\rightarrow0}\over{\longrightarrow}\ 0.$$

Comment: Related post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/891204/solve-lim-x-to-0x-sin-frac1x-using-lim-theta-to-0-frac-sin-t Found through [catalog of limits](https://mathindex.wordpress.com/limits-with-sine-at-zero/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect, cause you used incorrect transform, but it has already been stated. I'll describe way to solve it.

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\sin(\frac{1}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}} \neq 1$$

**Hint**: Solution is well-known trick. Note $(\forall x \in \mathbb{R})\left(\sin(x) \in[-1;1]\right)$ (obvious) and use [squeeze theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem) to solve it.

---

Note simple implication.

$$ \left(\forall h \in \mathbb{R}\right) \left(\sin h \in [-1;1]\right) \Longrightarrow (\forall x,h \in \mathbb{R})(|x \cdot \sin h| \leq |x|)$$

So, true is inequality $|x \cdot \sin \frac{1}{x}| \leq |x|$, therefore (and because module is always non-negative) using squeeze theorem you receive limit.

$$\left(0 \leq\left | \lim_{x \to 0} x\cdot \sin \frac{1}{x} \right | \leq \lim_{x \to 0} \left| x \right| = 0 \right)\Longrightarrow \lim_{x \to 0}x \cdot \sin(x) = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

You cant do this because

$$\sin(1/x)$$ isnt defined. So you cant use the fact that

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \sin(\alpha)/\alpha = 1$$

Comment: The function $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ is certainly defined;  what exactly do you mean?

Comment: At $x=0$ it isnt.

Comment: Oh, ok.  But more important than $f(x)$ not being defined at $x=0$, the limit to zero is also not defined.  I see what you mean.